# How to publish UWP app specifically for Xbox?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-dev-center

Is there a way to target Xbox device family specifically when creating a new UWP application? Thus making that application package unavailable for the other platforms, while potentially have a different package for other platforms?

Currently I'm trying to create a package for Xbox only by adding

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Xbox" MinVersion="10.0.14000.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14000.0" />
```

to the `package.appxmanifest`. Unfortunately this gives permission error on uploading via the dev center:

`Package acceptance validation error: The package *.appx targets the following Windows 10 device families for which you don't have permission(s): Windows.Xbox`

I think this is the correct way to do it and that the permissions might be granted somewhen after the anniversary update? When will publishing be possible? Or is there another program you have to sign up to for being allowed to publish an Xbox only application / get the required permission?

Comment: The store does not accept UWP App for XBOX yet. Some of developers - like as baconit - are 'invited' but others are not. There are no announcement about publishing UWP app for xbox. I'm also waiting it 1 year..

Comment: @pnp0a03 Do you happen to know whether there is anything one can do about it? I mean, the anniversary update is out. I expected a release for Xbox as well, including an open app store (I think it was also 'announced' at build16).
Is there a possibility to apply for this program/status baconit takes part in?

Comment: At the release note of AU SDK, MS says 'Later this month' ... :(  https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/08/02/windows-10-anniversary-update-sdk-14393/   and I don't have more information about this. They ... XBOX team ... have a problem about developer relation and sharing information, I believe. Too late, Too little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Windows Store is not ready to accept XBOX app. As pnp0a03 [mentioned](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/08/02/windows-10-anniversary-update-sdk-14393/), Microsoft will publish the new Dev Center feature and publish more details about publishing XBOX target app in Store, maybe later this month

Setting `TargetDeviceFamily` dependency is the right direction, the current available device families are `Windows.Universal`, `Windows.Mobile`, `Windows.Desktop`. Please waiting for the updates from Windows Store side.

Comment: Just a quick follow up - the store update is live since around the end of August and targeting different platforms with different packages works nicely.